# iPad not loading all HTML5 elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing this web app, which has quite a lot of .png's on it so it is relatively heavy (5MB). The problem I have is, that iPad seems not to be loading all elements every time I start the webapp in homescreen mode.

The app is basically a bunch of DIV's with background images for them which are "nice buttons" and js code running. Suddenly the image is not loaded, so I see no button, but I can press it and the functionality is there, so my JS code is loading and working. I suspect it has something to do with having too much images, so these don't get loaded if the ipad thinks it has no ressources for them -

Does anyone had such experience?

Comment: Without a link, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: Hi, the webapp is not published, it is designed to run on a LAN, sorry. I thought someone may have experienced this type of problem before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not the iPad or HTML 5. My Webapp is loading a lot of images and on the server side I have IIS / ASP .NET in an XP machine. The MaxConnections of the IIS is set by default to 10. As it gets flooded by requests from the App, it locks randomly some images and the iPad (or any browser) cannot load them (403 error). Increasing the MaxConnections parameter to the maximum value of 40 solved the problem:

{C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript adsutil.vbs SET w3svc/1/MaxConnections 40}

Now I want to detect these 403 errors to warn user if it may still happen, but that's another story (and another question in StackOverflow)...

Comment: Install NGINX on Linux. And spend your time on Development not on analyzing IIS problems with 40 Connections